# Django 1.5 raises UnicodeDecodeError when persisting uploaded file

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-forms

This problem started occurring when I updated my project's django version to 1.5.x.

My problem is that when using mysql as a backend and I upload a file and attempt to save the chunks of that file onto another model I get a UnicodeDecodeError.

In django 1.4.x there are no errors thrown and the related model gets persisted.

Example project to recreate:
https://github.com/imtapps/fileuploaderror

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class LongBlob(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "longblob"   

class Document(models.Model):
    document = LongBlob()

class Book(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from spikeapp.models import Document, Book

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    upload_file = forms.FileField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cleaned_data['upload_file'].open()
        data = ''.join([chunk for chunk in self.cleaned_data['upload_file'].chunks()])
        self.cleaned_data['upload_file'].close()
        Document.objects.create(document=data)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('description',)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from spikeapp.forms import BookForm

class FileView(FormView):
    template_name = 'file.html'
    form_class = BookForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(FileView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is the exception:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  165.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/home/appsdev/Projects/blobspike/spikeapp/views.py" in form_valid
  11.         form.save()
File "/home/appsdev/Projects/blobspike/spikeapp/forms.py" in save
  12.         Document.objects.create(document=data)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in create
  149.         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  416.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  650.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  215.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1675.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  937.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  45.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in last_executed_query
  243.         return cursor._last_executed.decode('utf-8')
File "/home/appsdev/.virtualenvs/blobspike/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py" in decode
  16.     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /
Exception Value: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 67: invalid start byte
```

Versions to replicate:
MySQLdb-Python = 1.2.4

Django = 1.5.4

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback? In the debug error view, there is a link to switch to a copy-able text-only traceback.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.4

Comment: Interesting, it's in recording the executed query that 1.5 fails, *not* on inserting the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stumbled on a bug in Django 1.5: [#19954 Storing of Binary fields leads to Exceptions](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19954).

The [committed fix](https://github.com/django/django/commit/86b1c316899f154b1800ab936330ac8924251e40) was to force decode the last executed query with 'replace':

```
return force_text(cursor._last_executed, errors='replace')
```

You can either edit your Django source code, or apply a monkeypatch:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseOperations

def fixed_last_executed_query(self, cursor, sql, params):
    return force_text(cursor._last_executed, errors='replace')

DatabaseOperations.last_executed_query = fixed_last_executed_query
```

Do so as early as possible, at the top of your `settings` module or package, for example.

I don't think the patch was backported; it so far only made it into the 1.6 development line, possibly because 1.6 added a new Binary field type.

Comment: Wow! I wish I could give you a thousand upvotes.  That exactly fixed my problem.  Thanks a lot Martijn.  We will just fork our django source.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work.  I tried editing the django code directly as in the "committed fix" also tried putting the above code snipit into my settings and neither worked.  - Any advice?

Comment: Without a traceback and more detail about your setup, it is next to impossible to say why this doesn't work for you. Sorry!